# AsyncTask with above API 11 makes app crashed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` and `gson` to parse the feed and everything works properly. But in one `fragment` I am getting forced close of my app on device above API 11. It is okay in devices below API 11. This is my code:

```
public class LatestSubmissions extends SherlockListFragment {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    LatestSubmissionsAdapter adapter = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> submissions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private GetSubmissionsListTask submissionTask = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getSherlockActivity());
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            prefs = getSherlockActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    CommonUtils.PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
            submissionTask = new GetSubmissionsListTask();
            submissionTask.execute(CommonUtils.USER_SUBMISSION_URL
                    + prefs.getString(CommonUtils.KEY_USER_ID, "339") + "/10");
        } else {
            MainActivity.networkAvailabilityNotice(getSherlockActivity());
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected class GetSubmissionsListTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStreamReader> {

        @Override
        protected InputStreamReader doInBackground(String... params) {
            return new JSONDownloader().getJSONStringFromUrl(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStreamReader isr) {
            if (isr != null) {
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getSherlockActivity();
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(isr);
                try {
                    reader.beginObject();
                    reader.nextName(); // name
                    reader.skipValue();
                    reader.nextName(); // uname
                    reader.skipValue();
                    String subs = reader.nextName(); // subs
                    if (subs.equals(CommonUtils.KEY_SUBMISSION)) {
                        reader.beginArray();
                        while (reader.hasNext()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            reader.beginArray();
                            reader.skipValue(); // submission id
                            String txt = "Latest problem";
                            Problems obj = MainActivity.problems.get(reader
                                    .nextInt());
                            if (obj != null) {
                                txt = obj.getProblemsInfo();
                            }
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_PROBLEM_ID, txt);
                            Verdict verdict = activity.verdicts.get(reader
                                    .nextString()); // verdict id
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_VERDICT_COLOR,
                                    verdict.verdictColorHex);
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_VERDICT_ID, verdict.name);
                            Double execTime = reader.nextDouble() / 1000; // execution
                                                                            // time
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_RUNTIME,
                                    execTime.toString() + "s");
                            reader.skipValue(); // submission time
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_LANGUAGE_ID,
                                    activity.languageCode.get(reader
                                            .nextString())); // lanugage
                                                                // id
                            map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_SUBMISSION_RANK,
                                    reader.nextString()); // rank
                            submissions.add(map);
                            reader.endArray();
                        }
                        reader.endArray();
                    }
                    reader.endObject();
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                        Log.e("GSON Parser",
                                "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
                Collections.reverse(submissions);
                adapter = new LatestSubmissionsAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                        submissions);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (submissionTask != null
                && submissionTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            submissionTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Ihave tested in several devices and emulators with different API level and it always forced close in my two devices with ICS and Jellybean.
This is my log cat:

```
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:174)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1263)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1005)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:811)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at me.kaidul.uhunt.RankList$GetRankListTask.onPostExecute(RankList.java:85)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at me.kaidul.uhunt.RankList$GetRankListTask.onPostExecute(RankList.java:1)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-19 01:57:16.961: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't figure it out how this is happening. I used almost the same type code in my other fragments and they worked well. Only two fragments incluing this encounter this problem.

Comment: Um, you chopped off the start of your logcat. What was the exception?

Comment: opps! I missed it while copying! I edited my question and now take a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the entire reading of the input stream in `doInBackground`. All you're doing now is opening the connection in `doInBackground` and obtaining a reader for the result. However, you're trying to actually read the data off the network in `onPostExecute`, which is executing on the main thread.

```
protected class GetSubmissionsListTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new JSONDownloader().getJSONStringFromUrl(params[0]);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = null;
        if (isr != null) {
            result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getSherlockActivity();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(isr);
            try {
                reader.beginObject();
                reader.nextName(); // name
                reader.skipValue();
                reader.nextName(); // uname
                reader.skipValue();
                String subs = reader.nextName(); // subs
                if (subs.equals(CommonUtils.KEY_SUBMISSION)) {
                    reader.beginArray();
                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        reader.beginArray();
                        reader.skipValue(); // submission id
                        String txt = "Latest problem";
                        Problems obj = MainActivity.problems.get(reader
                                .nextInt());
                        if (obj != null) {
                            txt = obj.getProblemsInfo();
                        }
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_PROBLEM_ID, txt);
                        Verdict verdict = activity.verdicts.get(reader
                                .nextString()); // verdict id
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_VERDICT_COLOR,
                                verdict.verdictColorHex);
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_VERDICT_ID, verdict.name);
                        Double execTime = reader.nextDouble() / 1000; // execution
                                                                        // time
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_RUNTIME,
                                execTime.toString() + "s");
                        reader.skipValue(); // submission time
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_LANGUAGE_ID,
                                activity.languageCode.get(reader
                                        .nextString())); // lanugage
                                                            // id
                        map.put(CommonUtils.KEY_SUBMISSION_RANK,
                                reader.nextString()); // rank
                        result.add(map);
                        reader.endArray();
                    }
                    reader.endArray();
                }
                reader.endObject();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (CommonUtils.isDebuggable) {
                    Log.e("GSON Parser",
                            "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                result = null;
            } finally {
                reader.close(); // always need to close, even after an exception
            }
        }
        if (result != null) Collections.reverse(result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            submissions = result; // do you still need this?
            adapter = new LatestSubmissionsAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                    result);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I grab the downloaded data and return them after downloading? like
`InputStreamReader isr = new JSONDownloader().getJSONStringFromUrl(params[0]);
return isr;`

Comment: the whole JSON processing should better be done in the background

Comment: @typedef - I posted a version of your code that should work (barring typos on my part). It moves the entire parsing process into the background thread. You could just grab the downloaded data, but there's no reason that I can see that the parsing itself needs to be done on the main thread, and as long as you need to go to the trouble of creating a background thread anyway, you might as well use it for all it's worth.

Comment: Thanks man, It works! I designed some other `fragment` in that wrong approach and they are working anyway. I am now going to change them. So what is the moral of this change? Should I do all the task from downloading feed to fill them into a data-structure in `doInBackground()` and do only the UI related work inside `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: @typedef - You need to do all network activity on a worker thread (like an `AsyncTask`). As long as you are setting up the thread anyway, do as much work as makes sense in the background. The less work you do on the UI thread, the less chance that the app will appear unresponsive to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You should do both the JSON reading and processing of the data in the background thread (`doInBackground`). Instantiating a stream does not read the whole of the stream into memory, invoking the read method read froms the stream and thus peforms network activity on the UI thread which is illegal on > API level 11.